# Travis does not have permission to pull git(hub) submodule

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I belong to github organization (as collaborator, not owner) and I have read/write access to two private repositories `org/a` and `org/b`. `org/a` has a dependency (as git submodule) on `org/b`. I want to build/test `org/a` in travis. I followed instructions from http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/#Using-an-existing-key and used following command (ofc I replaced `org/main` with my `org/a`):

```
$ travis sshkey --upload ~/.ssh/id_rsa -r org/main
Key description: Key to clone myorg/lib1 and myorg/lib2
updating ssh key for myorg/main with key from ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Current SSH key: Key to clone myorg/lib1 and myorg/lib2
```

<s>In travis settings for `org/a` I can see uploaded SSH key, but still when I run build process travis throws error that it does not have access to pull `org/b` repo:</s>

```
Installing an SSH key from: repository settings
Key fingerprint: 14:23:69:a0:27:c0:39:14:c2:81:71:af:2b:07:14:0a
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git@github.com:org/b.git org/b
Cloning into 'org/b'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.34.272.118' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What I am doing wrong?

---

Edit: I am blind. After uploading SSH key travis does not throw error when pulling git submodule, but when pulling `org/a` (main) repo (the one it is supposed to build):

```
Installing an SSH key from: repository settings
    Key fingerprint: 14:23:69:a0:27:c0:39:14:c2:81:71:af:2b:07:14:0a
    $ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git@github.com:org/a.git org/a
    Cloning into 'org/a'...
    Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.34.272.118' to the list of known hosts.
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

---

Edit: I realized that in `~/.ssh` directory I have other ssh keys:

```
$ ls ~/.ssh
github_rsa  github_rsa.pub  id_rsa      id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

So I guess I should upload `github_rsa` instead of `id_rsa`. However, for some reason, I don't remember passphrase to `github_rsa` - what should I do in this situation?

---

Edit: I've just uploaded `id_rsa.pub` to my github account and now Travis successfuly pulls main repo (`org/a`) but still it does not have permission to pull git submodule:

```
Submodule 'b' (https://github.com/org/b.git) registered for path 'b'
$ git submodule update
Cloning into 'b'...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/org/b.git/'
Clone of 'https://github.com/org/b.git' into submodule path 'b' failed
```

---

**SOLVED**: I was using HTTPS url for submodule -> changed it to SSH (git@github.com:org/b.git) and it works. To update submodule URL just edit `.gitmodules` file and then run `git submodule sync`

Comment: If you don't remember the passphrase you should just remove the ssh key from every service and generate a new one. Faster than trying to brute force crack the passphrase